# How to import Vue.js correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am starting with Vue.js, and I am wondering how to import it properly, in order to bundle it with Webpack.
All the examples in the documentation seem to assume that a `Vue` object is already present.

This is what I tried:

```js
const Vue = require('vue')
```

and also

```js
const Vue = require('vue').Vue
```

and then

```js
var app = new Vue({ <options> })
```

This file is then bundled with Webpack and referenced in my HTML index file.
But I am getting this error in the browser (in both cases):

> Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor

Comment: Why not using Vue CLI ? Check [this guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)

Comment: @Fabjan Thanks, I have seen that. I would prefer to keep my existing Webpack build, which I have just set up. See the about-to-get-accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way, if you are using ES6, is to use

```
import Vue from 'vue';
var app = new Vue({ <options> })
```

Comment: This looks better, I was not even aware that `import` and `require` would work differently. Now I am getting this error: "[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build." Do you know how to fix that also?

Comment: I think you still have to install and configure vue template compiler with WebPack 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

Comment: If you solved the issue, please accept as answer! Cheers!

Comment: That last link you sent part, the Webpack section, is presumably what I have been missing. I will not forget to accept your answer once I verified it. This seems to be the solution that I am looking for in the context of my existing Webpack build.